# Detecting Intersections on Android Using Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, android-gps

So, was hoping a more advanced developer would be able to give some insight. I am developing an app, and trying to use real-time tracking for users.

Once they are close to a turn or a crosswalk for example (paths crossing basically), the application would send an audio alert.

Is anyone familiar with the API that I need to figure this out? I know that Geo Coding or Inverse Geocoding is offered, but I was reading that not during real time.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You can always do it the hard way: Get OpenStreetMap vector map data e.g. from MapBox or Mapzen (nicer option) and detect intersections from the vector map data. At an intersection the intersecting streets share a coordinate point, so coordinate points that appear more than once in the data are intersections. I know it's possible as I have done it, but I won't go into details because I'm working on proprietary code.

Comment: Alternatively you could have a look at geonames.org APIs like [findNearestIntersection](http://www.geonames.org/maps/us-reverse-geocoder.html#findNearestIntersection) and [findNearestIntersectionOSM](http://www.geonames.org/maps/osm-reverse-geocoder.html#findNearestIntersectionOSM).

Comment: oh thank you for this, definitely helpful